# C# OracleDbType equivalent - for Oracle datatype char

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I want to pass a single CHAR to an oracle sp.

I tried using:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("i_flag", OracleDbType.Varchar2, flag, ParameterDirection.Input);
```

where flag is a C# char but it gives Overflow exception.

I also tried:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("i_flag", OracleDbType.Char, flag, ParameterDirection.Input);
```

but it gives same exception.

Even the below gives the same exception:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("i_flag", OracleDbType.Varchar2, flag.ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
```

Can you please tell what is the correct parameter type that I should pass.

Thanks,
Varun

Comment: Please check the variable size and the size of data passed from front end.

Comment: the variable is declared as CHAR(200). What size/type of C# data would it happily accept. :S

Comment: Maximum it can have 2000 bytes.

Comment: @user96403, maybe it's a UTF problem, try using `NChar`

Comment: Thanks techdo and Cade. Actually I pass it a char flag.             int s = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(flag); The value of s is 1. Even NChar doesn't fix it.

Comment: Which variable is declared as CHAR(200)? An Oracle column? That would be a very unusual data type and size combination. VARCHAR2 would be more common.

Comment: The DBAs tell me that it is supposed to take one char only and that it is not declared as aa CHAR(200). Only when I try to Run it in my SQL Developer I can see it as CHAR(200). May be I'll try some more combinations and then request my DBAs to change it to varchar2  ... or to something else that's not so rigid. Thanks all!

Comment: @user96403, that's strange... I'd think that since it's a parametr to a stored procedure then you don't specify the length of a char. I' still suspect the UTF, AFAIK in c# the char is a 2 byte, so if your DB's character set isn't UTF you'll need to use NCHAR in the DB SP or somehow send the value as one byte...

Answer (score 0):

More analysis revealed that the overflow was due to some arithmetic operation being done in stored procedure.

We need to truncate the decimal before sending it to .NET

Something similar to https://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=231945

Thanks for all the help though.